# Check jwt token when project start in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I need to check jwt Token in Asp Core .

I create this extension method for inject in Service :

```
public static class AddJWTAuthntication
{
    public static void AddJWTAuthnticationInjection(this IServiceCollection services,SiteSetting siteSetting)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            var securityKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(siteSetting.JwtSetting.SecretKey);
            var ValidatePrameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                //Tlorance for Expire Time and Befor Time of Token .
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
                RequireSignedTokens = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(securityKey),
                // I Need Check Expire Token or Not
                RequireExpirationTime = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = siteSetting.JwtSetting.Audience,
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = siteSetting.JwtSetting.Issuer

            };
            options.SaveToken = true;
            options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            options.TokenValidationParameters = ValidatePrameters;
        });
    }
}
```

and use it in service extension in StartUp :

```
           services.AddJWTAuthnticationInjection(_siteSetting);
```

and this is my `Configure` :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseCors(builder => builder
                     .AllowAnyHeader()
                     .AllowAnyMethod()
                     .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                     .AllowCredentials()
                    );
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
}
```

Now when I run the project it go to the `AddJWTAuthnticationInjection` for check validation but when I send the request it not go to `AddJWTAuthnticationInjection` for check Token Validation .

I need to reverse that, when user send a request it check the Validation of Token .

What's the problem? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This is not about token validation!
You are setting up the ASP.NET Core's `Authentication Middleware` with your settings so this process needs to be executed once and it happens at the start-up of your application.

The token validation happens internally in the `Authentication Middleware` (where you have used `app.UseAuthentication()` in the `Configure` method of the `StartUp.cs`).
So you don't need to worry about the process of validation, you just take care of the settings you did in your `AddJWTAuthnticationInjection` method.

- You have misplaced the Authentication Middleware and Authorization Middleware in your configure method. The Authentication Middleware needs to come before Authorization Middleware like this

  ```
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseAuthorization();
  ```
- Don't forget to add the `[Authorize]` Attribute on your controller to enable the token validation

Comment: i using the[Authorize] on my controller but when i send exipred token it not checked it

Comment: @Kianoush lifetime validation is done by ValidateLifetime = true which you have already added, so try fixing the middleware problem that I mentioned. Also, check the diagnostics window logs to find out whats happening.